# Is there any way to skip migrations which are failing?

Tags: rest, migration

I want to run migration on my server for ruby on rails project but I am getting this kind of error with postgres-

PGError: ERROR:  relation "last_message_read" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "last_message_read" ("id" serial primary key, "message" character varying(255), "company_id" integer)

So, I want to continue with my migration but it is not happening - I want to ignore those migration which are failing and continue with the rest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's wrong with your migrations.  Just reset your db (`rake db:reset`).

Comment: I would suggest making a backup of the data if there is any before doing the reset.

Comment: I know about reset but is there any to ignore the errors comes runtime.